# Render a gif or png when using QuickGraph (instead of a .dot file)

Tags: c#, graph, quickgraph

I m trying out quickgraph and when I remder like this:

```
var graphviz = new GraphvizAlgorithm<string, SEdge<string>>(g);     
graphviz.ImageType = GraphvizImageType.Gif;
var output = graphviz.Generate(new FileDotEngine(), "graph");
```

of course i get a Dot file called graph, I m pretty sure there are other ways, or maybe I need to transform the dot file into png some other way?
I know I could use gedit.exe but there must be a programmatic way to generate an image
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I m using [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/), in the bin folder of the installation there is a tool called **dot.exe** to use it from the command line I m doing something like:

```
dot -Tpng graph.dot > graph.png
```

Then use *Process* to call it